# Bug in parsing args with getopts in bash

Tags: bash, getopts

I was trying to modify the [bd](https://github.com/vigneshwaranr/bd) script to use `getopts`. I am a newbie at bash scripting

my script is

```
while getopts ":hvis:d:" opt
do
...
done

...

echo $somedirpath
cd "$somedirpath"
```

this runs fine when doing

```
$ ./bd -v -i -s search
```

or

```
$ ./bd -is search -d dir
```

But when running it like this

```
$ . ./bd -s search
```

`getopts` doesn't read the arguments at all. And all the variables I set in the `while` loop according to the arguments are all not set, so the script no longer works. Please help!

Comment: Why do you need to source the script?

Comment: @choroba The directory doesn't change without that (`cd` in the script has no effect in the first two cases)

Comment: Cannot reproduce in `bash` 3.2 or `bash` 4.2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Setting `OPTIND=1` before invoking `getopts` works fine.

The problem is that `getopts` relies on `OPTIND` to loop through the arguments provided, and after sourcing the script, it will be set to some value greater than 1 by `getopts` according to how many arguments you pass. This value gets carried over even after the script ends(because its being sourced). So the next time its sourced, `getopts` will pick up from that `OPTIND`, rather than starting from 1!

This might cause strange behaviour with other scripts, and I don't know how safe this is. But it works!

For a better workaround, I think what @tripleee suggests looks safe and robust.

Answer (score 7):

When you source a script, the arguments parsed by `getopts` are those of the current shell, not the parameters on the `source` command line.

The common workaround is to have your script merely print the path, and invoke it like `cd "$(bd)"` instead (perhaps indirectly through a function or alias).

Comment: But `echo "$@"` shows me the correct args, even when sourcing the script?

Comment: Plus, that won't react to error statements from the script very well.

Comment: @tripleee: from `help source`: "If any ARGUMENTS are supplied, they become the positional parameters when FILENAME is executed." In other words, inside the sourced script, the arguments are inherited *if you didn't specify any arguments* to the `source` command; otherwise, you do indeed get the specified arguments.

Comment: (Yes, it's a bash extension. Also a ksh extension. And probably others. The question is tagged bash.)

Comment: The script behind the Github link has a `#!/bin/sh` shebang line, so I guess actually the tag is wrong. But thanks for the additional information.

Comment: somehow setting `OPTIND` to `1` before invoking getopts seems to work fine. But I took to a different approach entirely, which does not use `getopts`. Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score -1):

Setting `OPTIND=1` may not work reliably on zsh. Try to use something different than `getopts`:

```
while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
do
   case "$1" in
   -h|--help)
      help
      return 0
      ;;
   -o|--option)
      option
      return 0
      ;;
   -*)
      echo "Invalid option '$1'. Use -h|--help to see the valid options" >&2
      return 1
      ;;
   *)
      echo "Invalid option '$1'. Use -h|--help to see the valid options" >&2
      return 1
   ;;
   esac
   shift
done
```

Comment: Why do you say it "may not work reliably on zsh"? What's the actual issue? Zsh's manual seems to say that setting OPTIND is ok: _"The first option to be examined may be changed by explicitly assigning to OPTIND."_ (And then there's [the POSIX text explicitly giving OPTIND=1 as the way to go here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html), but of course zsh isn't bound by that.)

Comment: @udiboy1209 partially described the issue. There was a problem with sourcing a script with 'OPTIND=1'.

Comment: umm, yes, if you source a script using `getopts`, it'll modify OPTIND, the same as any call to getopts in the same context. Which is why one needs to reset it before processing a new set of args. I can't see their answer saying resetting it wouldn't work. I only see that claim in this answer, and don't see any grounds for that claim, or an example of it.

Comment: I don't quite remember all the issues I had but I managed to make 'getopts' work with source in bash and still had some problems with 'zsh'. It looked like a bug and I didn't find any explanation. I suggested a solution that helped me. It just works, 'getopts' didn't.